# Why doesn't c++11 allow direct-list-initialization with auto

Tags: c++, c++11, auto, type-deduction

My friend told me that

```
auto x1 = {3}; // x1 is std::initializer_list<int>
auto x2{1, 2}; // error: not a single element
auto x3{3};    // x3 is int
```

I don't quite understand why `auto x2{1, 2};` is illegal, can't it be deduced directly as `std::initializer_list<int>`?

Comment: [First paper](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3681.html) and [the second one](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3922.html). Your code `auto x2{1,2};` compiles fine with G++ < 5.0 version, see it on godbolt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The standard has intentionally restricted this case.

```
auto x2{1, 2}; // error: not a single element
```

> Auto and braced initializers cause a teachability problem; we want to teach people to use uniform initialization, but we need to specifically tell programmers to avoid braces with auto. In C++14, we now have more cases where auto and braces are problematic; return type deduction for functions partially avoids the problem, since returning a braced-list won't work as it's not an expression. However, returning an auto variable initialized from a braced initializer still returns an initializer_list, inviting undefined behaviour. Lambda init captures have the same problem. This paper proposes to change a brace-initialized auto to not deduce to an initializer list, and to ban brace-initialized auto for cases where the braced-initializer has more than one element.

See the ISO/IEC JTC1/SC22/WG21 C++ Standards Committee paper on [Auto and braced-init-lists](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3681.html) for more details.

Answer (score -2):

It is, according to my compiler, because x2 is a scalar and can therefore only have one index. The following, however compiles because it is an array and arrays have two indices.

auto x2[]{1,2};